# Modify an object value in array using swift

Tags: ios, swift

i am new to swift.
I want to know how to modify an object in a for-each loop using swift.
for example:

struct MyCustomObject 
{
    var customValue: String?
}

let myArray: [MyCustomObject?]

```
for anObject:MyCustomObject in myArray {
    anObject.customValue = "Hello" // <---Cannot assign to property: 'anObject' is a 'let' constant 
}
```

so , what should I do if i want to change the object value in a for-loop.
I tired adding "var" before anObject, but it doesnt work!! (the objects in the array still remain unchanged.)

For objective C , it is easy,

NSMutableArray * myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

```
for (MyCustomObject * object in myArray) 
{ 
  object.customValue = "Hello" 
}
```

Comment: Is `myArray` a `let` or `var`?

Comment: myArray is a "let".
 enumerate your array and change the array element using the index<--- anymore example?

Comment: Do you want the changes to stay permanently in your array or do you want them only temporary during the loop?

Comment: I want to change "anObject.customValue" for permanently!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because values stored in an array are immutable. You have 2 options:

1: change `MyCustomObject` to a class:

```
class MyCustomObject { var customValue: String? }
```

2: iterate by index

```
for i in 0..<myArray.count {
    if myArray[i] != nil {
        myArray[i]!.customValue = "Hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

```
 let temObj:MyCustomObject  = anObject  
 temObj.customValue = "Hello"
```